# Get index of row where pandas column contains regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am checking to see if a pandas column matches a pre-defined regex, using `.any()` to get the first match if found. However, I need to return the index/row where this match occurred so that I can get the value of another column in that row.

I have the below to check where the reg_ex pattern exists in `df['id_org']`

```
if df['id_org'].str.contains(pat=reg_ex, regex=True).any()
```

Once the above evaluates to true, **how do I get the index/row that caused the expression to evaluate to true?** I would like to use this index so that I can access another column for that same row using pandas `df.at[index, 'desired_col']` or .`iloc` functions.

In the past I have done: `df.at[df['id_org'][df['id_org'] == key].index[0], 'desired_col']` however, I can't use this line of code any more because I am no longer checking for an exact string "key" match bur rather when a regex now matches in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) combined with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
reg_ex = 'xxx'

s = df['id_org'].str.contains(pat=reg_ex, regex=True)
out = s.idxmax() if s.any() else None
```

Or [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```
s = df['id_org'].str.contains(pat=reg_ex, regex=True)
out = s[s].first_valid_index()
```

Example of outputs:

```
# reg_ex = 'e'
1

# reg_ex = 'z'
None
```

Used input:

```
  id_org
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
3    cde
```

##### all matches

```
s = df['id_org'].str.contains(pat=reg_ex, regex=True)
out = s.index[s]
```

Example for the regex `'e'`: `Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')`